# How to disable built-in keyboard on OS X 10.9.1?

Tags: keyboard, macos

Before **10.9.1**, I can disable/enable the built-in keyboard of my Air with the commands:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext
```

But it seems after I updated to 10.9.1, the commands don't work anymore. Maybe the update made the command moot?

Also, I was getting desperate (thus, stupid) in trying to disable the built-in keyboard, that I tried deleting the `AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext` directory, thinking it would just get regenerated after a restart. Well, it didn't get regenerated. My built-in keyboard still works, but I'm not sure if the missing directory will have some hidden side-effects.

Comment: This is strange: I just tried on my 2009 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks and your `kextunload` commands work fine to disable and enable the keyboard (just copied and pasted with the mouse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <devicevendordef>
    <vendorname>APPLE</vendorname>
    <vendorid>0x05f3</vendorid>
  </devicevendordef>
  <deviceproductdef>
    <productname>LAPTOPKEYBOARD</productname>
    <productid>0x1234</productid>
  </deviceproductdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <device_only>DeviceVendor::APPLE, DeviceProduct::LAPTOPKEYBOARD</device_only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x00, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x01, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x02, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x03, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x04, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x05, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x06, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x07, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x08, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x09, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x0a, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x0b, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x0c, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x0d, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x0e, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x0f, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x10, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x11, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x12, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x13, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x14, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x15, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x16, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x17, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x18, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x19, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x1a, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x1b, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x1c, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x1d, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x1e, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x1f, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x20, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x21, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x22, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x23, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x24, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x25, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x26, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x27, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x28, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x29, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x2a, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x2b, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x2c, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x2d, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x2e, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x2f, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x30, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x31, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x32, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x33, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x34, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x35, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x36, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x37, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x38, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x39, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x3a, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x3b, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x3c, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x3d, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x3e, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x3f, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x40, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x41, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x42, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x43, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x44, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x45, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x46, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x47, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x48, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x49, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x4a, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x4b, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x4c, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x4d, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x4e, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x4f, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x50, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x51, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x52, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x53, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x54, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x55, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x56, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x57, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x58, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x59, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x5a, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x5b, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x5c, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x5d, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x5e, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x5f, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x60, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x61, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x62, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x63, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x64, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x65, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x66, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x67, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x68, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x69, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x6a, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x6b, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x6c, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x6d, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x6e, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x6f, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x70, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x71, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x72, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x73, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x74, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x75, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x76, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x77, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x78, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x79, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x7a, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x7b, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x7c, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x7d, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x7e, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x7f, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x80, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x81, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x82, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x83, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x84, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x85, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x86, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x87, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x88, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x89, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x8a, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x8b, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x8c, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x8d, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x8e, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x8f, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x90, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RawValue::0x91, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Replace `0x1234` with the ID shown by EventViewer (`/Applications/KeyRemap4MacBook.app/Contents/Applications/EventViewer.app`).