# Cannot load the Built-in keyboard kext on Macbook pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, kernel, kernel-extensions

I needed to disable my internal keyboard for a while. What I did was try this:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
```

Though that showed an error:

```
(kernel) Can't unload kext com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard; classes have instances:
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard class AppleUSBTCKeyboard has 6 instances.
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).
```

The way I tried to deal with it was to drag it out. I then dragged it in when I wanted to re-enable the keyboard. So I dragged it in, and issued:

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
```

And the following error showed up:

```
TopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
/System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) authentication failure (file ownership/permissions); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
```

I noticed that when I dragged it to the desktop, I gained privileges to the kext. So I tried this to stop the above error:

```
sudo chown root /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
```

That had no success in fixing the error and the keyboard did not show up. I know that there is kextutil which might be the new kextload and kextunload as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114573/how-to-disable-built-in-keyboard-on-os-x-10-9-1). It is a similar question, though the answer is not what I wanted.

If it is possible to reload the keyboard kext with kextutil, I would like a tutorial on that and an explanation to why the authentication failure shows.

Comment: As no-one's picked this up yet, I'm tempted to say - try running the 10.10.3 combo updater & see if it puts things back as they should be. [I have no clue how to do it otherwise]

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the suggestion. I greatly appreciate it :)